# Connecting to Snowflake via their ODBC driver in PHP using Windows

Tags: php, windows, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, driver

I'm trying to connect Snowflake via their ODBC driver in PHP. But I could not able to connect and could not see any error as well. The below php code,

```
$dsn = "Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver;Server=".SNOWFLAKE_HOST;
$dsn .= ";Account=" . SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT;
$dsn .= ";Schema=" . SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA;
$dsn .= ";Warehouse=" . SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE;
$dsn .= ";Database=" . SNOWFLAKE_DATABASAE;
$conn_id = odbc_connect($dsn, SNOWFLAKE_USER, SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD);
```

I have installed odbc driver and tested snowflake connection. It's working fine. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.